# Please add the "Why are upvotes and downvotes here different?" text to Meta SE site FAQs

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, voting, meta

I'm finding the people not familiar with SE/SO-trilogy don't understand how voting should work on Meta Stack Exchange sites. Can this text on the Meta SO FAQ please be added to Meta SE site FAQs as well?

> **Why are upvotes and downvotes here
>   different?**
>
> Voting here works a bit differently
>   from other Stack Exchange sites. On
>   Meta Stack Overflow, voting is used to
>   express agreement or disagreement, not
>   to point out a lack of quality or
>   helpfulness. Please don't be concerned
>   if you receive downvotes – members of
>   the community may simply disagree with
>   your bug, feature request, support
>   question, or the nature of the
>   discussion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ok, I added this -- I agree that it's probably helpful after adding it here.