# Proposal for debugging questions

Tags: discussion

I was thinking about these type of questions cropping up rather often which could easily be solved by a debugger.

If people don't get reputation, the problem may die out (or decrease), and people who would be willing to help still can do this.

So I thought what to do with such questions and came up with this proposal.

A question should be flagable as being a debugging question. The process would be similar to voting to close, by having an additional option. However, such a question should not be closed, but stay open for providing answers. The difference would be that any activity on such a question (up and downvoting, accepting, etc) should give no reputation changes.
If it turns out that a question would be a good question for Stack Overflow after all, then it could be submitted for unlocking it, just like a reopen vote. If that vote is successfull, the reputation activities could be applied, as if the question was never flagged as debugging.
Alternatively, such a question could automatically submitted to an unlock vote, when an answer is accepted.

Now I'm aware that SO is not a debugging site by its own definition, but fact is, that it is used as such. You could argue that such questions can be closed, but I'm sure this is not going to happen as it can be seen now. I found SO via Google. When I'm programming, I try to solve my problems myself and SO hasn't changed that. So when I tried to use Google to find solutions, I was refered so often to SO, that finally I decided to join it. I guess many people (especially beginners) come here through Google as well, so this problem of people asking for code that should be debugged will not go away.

Comment: I take the downvotes as disagreement, but it would be nice to leave at least a comment what the disagreement is about.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136574/do-we-need-a-debugging-help-tag

Comment: Downvotes can also mean you took the fourth paragraph to explain what you wanted instead of putting that request/idea in the first paragraph

Comment: @random, thanks, I was not aware of that, so I reordered the paragraphs.

Comment: I don't dislike this. There is a certain amount of borderline debugging questions that we'll always have and that won't go away. Finding a way to deal with those might be very helpful

Comment: This wouldn't make much sense on other non coding sites in the network  and would add complexity to a system that already causes confusion amongst new users

Comment: @Rory, What confusion do you mean?

Comment: @Devolus New users still aren't sure about on hold and closure and what it means with regards to editing/the potential for reopening - this could just complicate things

Comment: @Rory, Since such a question wouldn't be locked, the user wouldn't notice it, unless there is some banner added to inform visitors of such a questions. The question is still open for answers, so it would be different to closed questions. A confusion could arise though, to realize why no rep is awarded though. But then you can tell him that he could have solved this by simple debugging, which may help for the next time.

Comment: Don't be discouraged by this particular idea being unpopular; the more brains working on the ["fix my codez" problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107116/are-code-troubleshooting-questions-really-what-we-want-to-encourage), the better.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, I'm not disappointed (maybe a little :) ) I just tried to provide a proposal and wanted to know what others think about it. After all, I find these debugging questions a bit frustrating. especially as I think that it takes more time to wait for an answer, then running the debugger myself. And considering that the other questions has -13 and mine currently only -7 is giving me hope. :P

Answer (score 9):

This doesn't solve the problem of the crap errr... noise that is called "debug this for me" or "find this typo for me."

Questions like that should just be closed and deleted (and possibly downvoted).

We don't need a way to handle debugging questions in order to allow them, we have to kill them with <strike>fire</strike> napalm IMHO.

Comment: If poeple don't get rep, it may well be that the noise is reduced. And saying how "it should be" doesn't change how it is. Just look at the SMS which was not intended for massive messaging. ;)

Comment: The noise will still be on the site. Getting in the way of the gems (which are already really hard to find). Your solution doesn't prevent that.

Comment: If you can also apply a filter to such questions it may help. Because those questions would at least be identifiable then. Now you have to wade through them.

Comment: And what happens if SO would implement your solution and OP accepts an answer and the thing becomes "unlocked"?

Comment: If it becomes unlocked, then it would be a valid questions just like if it were never marked as "debugging". So the rep is applied at this time. After all, it may turn out that the solution was indeed something deeper than at first glance and such questions with solutions is what we want to see on SO, right?

Comment: Exactly. So the crap debugging question will be poured back in the system and more noise is added. OP will accept the answer telling him he missed a semicolon on line 9. Doesn't make it a good question.

Comment: If the community would vote such a question to be unlocked than this would indeed be the case. But this means that the whole moderating system is at question because you are also relying on the community to moderate the questions right now as well. So I doubt that trivial questions would be voted to unlock.

Comment: @Devolus I think his point is that you're coming up with an extremely over-complicated solution that would require a lot of effort and new factors in the system, when there's a much simpler (and more effective) solution at hand - just delete the crap.

Comment: @animuson, And "just delete it" apparently works very well. :p

Comment: You may be overlooking the fact that there's a fair number of people on SO, @Devolus, who aren't motivated by rep, but by the belief that anyone with a problem and a keyboard should be "helped". Those folks won't be deterred by removing the rep incentive, and the questions will continue to recieve responses. Preventing rep gain might have some effect, but I'm not sure it's enough for the complexity.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, I'm aware of that. I guess if people were here only for the rep, the site would never have taken off. :) The main problem is IMO that beginners will continue to hit SO as one of their first links coming up on google, and considering that there are currently more than 100K questions in the review process for closing, this problem will not be solved by thinking that "just delete it" will help. In fact, the number of closing review postings is ever increasing since I joined.

Comment: Well, sure, @Devolus, nobody signed up for SO solely to make a number representing imaginary stature go up (at least, let's hope not). You're right, there's a lot of janitorial work building up, but I really don't like the idea of officially condoning candy bar wrappers on the ground because we're too busy with the dog poop and we can't get to them all.