# Can't get any answers and can't contact users who previously answered related questions

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, unanswered-questions

I'm trying to solve a problem which only one other person seems to have posted a question about on Stack Overflow and has answered [their own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272355/how-to-post-a-tweet-from-an-android-app-to-one-specific-account).

The problem is that their answer doesn't completely solve my problem. I want to ask this person by way of a comment to their own answer, but I don't have the requisite number of reputation points to be allowed to post a comment.

I posted my own related question a week ago, but have received no answers at all. I can't contact the original member directly, so I (rather cheekily, I know) posted an answer to their question, but it was unceremoniously deleted within the hour by a 'diamond' moderator.

Unfortunately, the moderator that deleted it didn't think to mention what I'm supposed to do in order to a: try to get an answer to my related question, or b: contact the original member without being able to comment.  The deleting moderator offered no help or suggestions, which surprises me.

Faced with nobody else on Stack Overflow seemingly being able to answer my direct question, can anybody give me any advice as to how I can continue the original post without being able to post a comment, AND/OR without being able to contact the person that seems to know the answer I'm looking for (whilst at the same time not upsetting the moderators)?

Comment: Having a read through your question on SO, contacting other users is not your problem. Your question is. That is a hell of a lot of text with a whole bunch of questions. The effort is appreciated. And details is always welcome. But even if I'm not your target audience, I did get a sense of "I'm not going to read through all that. I've lost track already". Is there no way in which you could narrow your question down to something more simply stated with a clear single question?

Comment: Looks like a fair question, I have started a small bounty on it to draw more attention. More than that we really can't do.

Comment: @Bart: I did wonder if that might be it.  I'm trying to only answer one question, but I added as much detail as possible to make it clear what I'd already tried.  But I'll edit it and try again - thanks.

Comment: @Sha Wiz Dow Ard: Thanks - let's see if that works :)

Comment: @Bart: Could you post your comment as an answer, so that I can vote it up?  I need to find out how to properly gain reputations, but I'm not doing very well so far.  I want to fully engage with the SO community, but even simply posting this question on Meta has soumehow earned me another "-1"!  Go figure!

Comment: Votes are different on Meta http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93758/please-add-the-why-are-upvotes-and-downvotes-here-different-text-to-meta-se-s

Comment: Maybe you should just ask Twitter. For all I know, tomorrow they could close all their services.

Comment: Did ask twitter.  No reply!

Answer (score 5):

Try answering few questions. Will get reputation and then the privilege to comment on posts.

As seen on https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment you can comment when you reach 50 points of reputation. It means 5 upvotes on answers, which for sure you can do with some effort.

Also try to make your questions more clear and concise. It will be a good way to have more people trying to answer your questions. I am sure there is more than one person who can help you with that specific problem.

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is that their answer doesn't completely solve my problem.

Then you have a different problem, making it legitimate that you create a new question for it.

> I want to ask this person by way of a comment to their own answer,

Then you are at the wrong site. StackOverflow is not a forum. It's not intended for you to ask a question to a specific user. Questions are aimed at the whole community, and mentions to other users in comments are designed to facilitate the clarification of existing questions, not to ask about new problems.

Comment: I want to do EXACTLY the same with my app as the person posting / answering the problem (NNorbi90). I have carried out the steps and written the code EXACTLY as posted by NNorbi90, but it doesn't work for me. So my problem is exactly the same as the original problem, but the answer doesn't solve it. That's why I didn't want to post another question, because my question is identical. SO is definitely the correct place for this. I only wanted to post a comment to NNorbi90's answer to find out if there is something else he/she did that isn't fully explained in thier answer.

Comment: @DDSports what Daniel means is that SO is not the place for you to ask NNorbi90 something. It's a place to ask the whole world something. Let go of the idea that NNorbi90 can help you, and concentrate on writing your question in a way that will lead to help from the larger community

Comment: @Kate: You're absolutely right. It wasn't my original plan to try and contact one specific member with one specific question. This contributor just happened to post the exact problem I had and posted an answer that was perfect for my app. I've spent days (no exageration) trawling through SO for a similar answer that might tell me why this answer didn't work for me, but without any luck. I then resorted to posting my own question that got no answers! Anyway, as Bart suggested, I've edited my question to be much less wordy and I've got my fingers crossed that somebody can help. Cheers!