# How do I check if a question author has found an (unposted) answer in the meantime?

Tags: support, answers

How do I check or ask whether somebody has found the answer to their own question? 
(I do not have enough reputation points to post it as a comment.)

Note that this is not the question about getting points. I suspect that the person may have  found the answer to their question, but did not post the answer. I would like to ask if the answer was found.

Comment: It is the "answer acceptation". Take the [tour](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Commenting reputation is easily achieved by suggesting 25 good edits.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183105/cant-get-any-answers-and-cant-contact-users-who-previously-answered-related-qu

Comment: worth reading about why contact options are limited/ non-existing: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user

Comment: also related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201849/how-to-handle-a-deliberate-duplicate-question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: also related perhaps: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134329/what-should-i-do-when-there-is-a-question-that-is-the-same-as-one-i-would-ask-bu

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP is asking about cases where OP has a question without an answer. That's the only time it makes sense to ask through a comment anyway. Also, an accepted answer doesn't make the answer correct or useful for anyone else. There's also some people who never accept answers.

Comment: Celaeno: the only place that answers show up here are in posted answers and sometimes in comments (what you’re reading right now is a comment; the smaller texts attached to posts). If there are no answers or comments useful to you under a question, that’s it, you’re out of luck. There is nowhere else on the site that people are discussing answers to that Q, and there’s no way to contact the OP of the question to ask them. No useful answers or comments == move on.

Comment: The potential duplicate does answer the question - it explains how the user can get the necessary rep to comment on another user's question, which is what they want to do.

Answer (score 4):

Some users leave means of contacting (email, Twitter, personal website) on their profile. If not, a comment is about the only option within the current (and, likely, future) Stack Exchange system. It's not exactly [what they're intended for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), but one could argue that you're "requesting clarification from the author". In any case, as soon as they respond, be a good citizen and clean up after yourself by deleting the comment(s).

> (I do not have enough reputation points to post it as a comment.)

That's too bad, but it's rather easy to earn 50 reputation to obtain this privilege. It's less than the association bonus, so if you do have experience about an entirely different topic which is covered on another Stack Exchange site, you'll be able to comment everywhere in the network.

Comment: Thanks @Glorfindel (and Olivia and Dan Bron), this seems to be the answer to my question, though not one that I was hoping for.

Comment: Possible related: https://xkcd.com/979/