# Add "Voting on meta sites is different" confirmation text before allowing a post on meta sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am suggesting building on [this suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93758/please-add-the-why-are-upvotes-and-downvotes-here-different-text-to-meta-se-s) and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87475/add-a-note-about-downvoting-on-meta), to add a confirmation "user must click through" message stating to the effect of what is said in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92745/193412)

> #### Why are upvotes and downvotes here different?
>
> Voting here works a bit differently from other Stack Exchange sites. On Meta Stack Overflow, **voting is used to express agreement or disagreement, not to point out a lack of quality or helpfulness**. Please don't be concerned if you receive downvotes – members of the community may simply disagree with your bug, feature request, support question, or the nature of the discussion.

This would be for **all** meta.whatever sites.

I know this is in the FAQ. But I find myself so often posting things like [this](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1945/policy-for-asking-hypothetical-questions-to-generate-more-good-content#comment2887_1945) on meta.workplace frequently, so obviously people are not finding this ahead of time.

Users would have to click acknowledgement to having read this message before being able to make their first meta post.

Comment: But only for new users. It could be a privilege to not see that message. Possibly 200 rep

Comment: The thing is that votes are also there to "point out a lack of quality or helpfulness"... They can do both here. Some posts are crap and get downvoted because of that. Some posts are good but get downvoted because we disagree.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest that this isn't a good idea.  It's too much extra hassle for a relatively unimportant detail.

However, the intent is a good one, so I'll suggest a counterproposal: put hovertext over the vote total (score) for lower-rep users (anyone who can't click to see votes, so currently 1000) that includes something like "Voting on meta is different; click to read more" and then clicking (currently < 1000 clicking does nothing) to get to that FAQ post.